# How to import Basemap (mpl) in Azure ML (section Notebooks)

Tags: python, azure, matplotlib-basemap, azure-machine-learning-service

how can I import Basemap (from mpl_toolkits.basemap) in Azure ML (in section Notebooks)? 
Is there a general way to import libraries in Azure ML? 
(current version is shown as Python 3.4.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:47:47) IPython: 5.1.0)

pip installs the GEOS package but there are missing dependencies (and I could export the GEOS_DIR)

> *Please install the corresponding packages using your
>       systems software management system (e.g. for Debian Linux do:
>       'apt-get install libgeos-3.3.3 libgeos-c1 libgeos-dev' and/or
>       set the environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location
>       where geos is installed (for example, if geos_c.h
>       is in /usr/local/include, and libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib,
>       set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local), or edit the setup.py script
>       manually and set the variable GEOS_dir (right after the line
>       that says "set GEOS_dir manually here".*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install `mpltoolkits.basemap` package via the command below in the notebook of Azure ML for Python3 successfully, please try it.

```
!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

According to the installation doc of Matplotlib, if the code `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` not works after installed it, try to check the package `geos` had been installed and via `!pip install geos` to fix it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not work in my case? So what I did is using conda instead -> !conda install -y basemap

Comment: @InLaw May you need to upgrade `pip` first via `!pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/nbcommon/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages